# How can I use WMI to find out the installed Exchange Version using C#?

Tags: c#, wmi

I would like to be able to query the Exchange version installed on our user's server. I understand that this can be done using WMI, but I'm having a hard time finding a simple explanation using Google. Any advice?

Comment: Why is there an email server running on your user's computer? Is it a server?

Comment: Yes - it's for diagnostic purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
string condition = "Vendor LIKE 'Microsoft%' AND Name = 'Exchange'";
string[] selectedProperties = new string[] { "Version" };
SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_Product", condition, selectedProperties);

using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
using (ManagementObjectCollection products = searcher.Get())
    foreach (ManagementObject product in products)
    {
        string version = (string) product["Version"];

        // Do something with version...
    }
```

That searches for instances of the [`Win32_Product` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa394378.aspx) where the `Vendor` property begins with `"Microsoft"` and the `Name` property is `"Exchange"`, and retrieves the `Version` property.  I don't have access to an installation of Exchange to know what those values will actually be.  Even better would be if you can determine what the `ProductID` property would be for Exchange so you can filter just based on that.

Note that not all installed applications are returned by `Win32_Product` (it seems to be mostly Microsoft applications and those with Windows Installer installers).  So, for all I know Exchange is not one of these applications!

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same question: Exchange (server) on user's computer?
btw, [here](http://robkennedy.com/2010/08/23/applicationlist-retrieving-a-list-of-installed-applications-using-wmi-using-c/) you can find a good sample source with explanations of how to retrieve list of installed applications on (any) windows pc, using WMI.

The idea behind this is using "SELECT * FROM Win32_Product" query from "\root\cimv2" to select list of applications.

each application item (implemented class) has it's own 'IdentifyingNumber', 'Description', 'Version', etc. which help you find your answer.